# thymeleaf layout dialect not working or missing something

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Hi so I am using Spring boot with thymeleaf and I wanted to use a header that is located in my layout.html file to decorate all of my pages.
I added the dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And in my layout.html I have this element

```
 <header >
   <div layout:fragment="header">
   // My header code
   </div>
 </header>
```

And the element I'm trying to replace is in my home.html

```
<html lang="en" 
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
  layout:decorate="layout">
```

And the element I'm trying to replace

```
 <header>
   <div layout:fragment="header">
   </div>
 </header>
```

What happens is when I load my home.html the page is empty and on inspection the body consists only of the header element with 970x0 size or smt. I have never used the layout dialect and I'm not sure if I have to make some configurations. Also I'm not sure if the home.html is also getting the style imports that are in the layout.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

- *common_head.html*: Header to be imported in other files:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head th:fragment="head">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
                initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <title th:text="#{title.head}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/main.css}" />
        <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/main.js}"></script>
    </head>
```

- *item-create.html* Thymeleaf template, which includes previous head-tag:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head th:insert="~{common_head :: head}"> />
    <body>...
```

The full example can be found in my German blog here:
https://agile-coding.blogspot.com/2020/11/thymeleaf-2.html